# column name [no-column-name] already exist issue in cfcsv tag?

Tags: csv, coldfusion, lucee

**I would try parse .csv file using cfcsv tag.**

- That works fine with original source file.
- If I'm edit that csv file cfcsv tag return column name [no-column-name] already exist issue

**How to solve that ?**

*Example code :*

```
<cfcsv action="parse" file="<fileName>" variable="myQuery" />
<cfdump var="#myQuery#" />
```

Comment: Give all your columns unique names.

Comment: Yeah I'm check that all columns have unique name. If I'm edit any values cfcsv tag return error.otherwise it's working stable.